# How reliable are the narrators in the writings of HP Lovecraft?

Tags: narrator, h-p-lovecraft

HP Lovecraft often tells his stories through the perspective of a narrator.

How reliable can these narrators be considered, and can he be said to have used unreliable narrators as a story device?

Comment: I've removed the request for literature recommendations because it would be an off-topic list question ([meta 1](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/should-recommendation-questions-be-on-topic), [meta 2](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/a-question-about-list-questions)). It's possible, even likely, that answers to the non-recommendation question will include sources anyways.

Comment: If you remove that, then the entire question will boil down to a Yes or no Answer and will likely be deleted. I am asking for textual examples, not a list. Please don't change the emphasis of the question.